# Whatsapp on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, whatsapp

Is it already possible to download `Whatsapp` on Ubuntu mobile through the software center? Or can someone show me how to download and install this step by step? I don't have an Ubuntu phone yet but I would love to try it but only if it is possible to run Whatsapp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no official Whatsapp client for Ubuntu phone till now, but there is a workaround to do that.

Please read this for more information http://www.whatsappfor.org/software/whatsapp-ubuntu-phone-touch/

Comment: Until WhatsApp bans you and whatever app you're using, from their servers. After that, well, you will be banned from WhatsApp, so I guess you will need to find some other tool to communicate. :)

Answer (score -2):

I asked this exact question in the Ubuntu app dev group just today.

Consensus is that it won't come anytime soon if at all. Workarounds might be possible in the future, but Whatsapp/Facebook is by no means interested in that(they love that lack of privacy)